# Memoizing fibonacci sequence in python

Tags: python, fibonacci, memoization

I have to write a `fib_memoize(n)` function that should be recursive but it should memoize its answer so that it's running time is `O(n)`.
This is what I have:

```
def fib_memoize(n):
    memo = {}
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    else:
        if n <=2:
            f = 1
        else:
            f = fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-2)

        memo[n] = f
        return f
```

This is giving me an assertion error saying `1 != 0`. What is this pointing to? What am I missing?

This is my `fib_recursive` function (passes the tests):

```
def fib_recursive(n):
    if n <=1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-2)
```

Comment: Could you explain to me why I see so many new users with improperly indented `def` lines?

Comment: It seems like the error you are referring to comes from the test framework. It's telling you that an input of 0 should return 1, but isn't, or vice-versa.

Comment: just memonize by storing fib numbers in a list. Get the next one by appending the sum of the previous two

Comment: @MadPhysicist because they don't know about `<ctrl-k>` so just indent the first line to get the pasted code to be formatted as code.

Comment: @AChampion. First time I heard about it too. I just click on the little button thingy in the toolbar :) That makes a lot of sense though.

Comment: This is a typical case of "How not to use recursion" and especially of "How not to teach recursion".

Answer (score 1):

Memoizing is usually done with a decorator over your original function, e.g.:

```
import functools

def memoize(fn):
    cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def memoizer(n):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = fn(n)
        return cache[n]
    return memoizer

@memoize
def fib_recursive(n):
    if n <=1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-2)
```

This turns the original `fib_recursive` function into a memoized function.

Comment: Or use the  one that [comes with python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) `@functools.lru_cache`. There's even a Fibonacci example in the docs.

Comment: This isn't really helpful to someone trying to understand basic concepts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the @functools.lru_cache. As you can tell from my question, I'm still a beginner